# Purged package still remained on the system

Tags: apt, package-management, php

I've purged `php` from my ubuntu 16.04 with the following command:

`sudo apt purge php`

I got the success message as far as I remember. But Apparently, `php` has still remained on my system. these are the pieces of evidence:

### **1)** `$ php -v`

Output:

```
PHP 7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

---

### 2) `apt-cache policy php`

Output:

```
php:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:7.0+35ubuntu6
  Version table:
     1:7.0+35ubuntu6 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

---

### 3) `dpkg -l | grep -E '^ii' | grep php`

Output:

```
ii  libapache2-mod-php7.0                         7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                      amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
ii  php-cli-prompt                                1.0.1+dfsg-1build1                           all          tiny helper prompting for user input
ii  php-common                                    1:35ubuntu6.1                                all          Common files for PHP packages
ii  php-composer-semver                           1.2.0-1build1                                all          Semver library that offers utilities, version constraint parsing and
ii  php-composer-spdx-licenses                    1.1.2-1build1                                all          SPDX licenses list and validation library
ii  php-gd                                        1:7.0+35ubuntu6                              all          GD module for PHP [default]
ii  php-json-schema                               1.6.1-1build1                                all          implementation of JSON schema
ii  php-mysql                                     1:7.0+35ubuntu6.1                            all          MySQL module for PHP [default]
ii  php-symfony-console                           2.7.10-0ubuntu2                              all          run tasks from the command line
ii  php-symfony-filesystem                        2.7.10-0ubuntu2                              all          basic filesystem utilities
ii  php-symfony-finder                            2.7.10-0ubuntu2                              all          find files and directories
ii  php-symfony-process                           2.7.10-0ubuntu2                              all          execute commands in sub-processes
ii  php7.0-cli                                    7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                      amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii  php7.0-common                                 7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                      amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP
ii  php7.0-curl                                   7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                      amd64        CURL module for PHP
ii  php7.0-gd                                     7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                      amd64        GD module for PHP
ii  php7.0-json                                   7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                      amd64        JSON module for PHP
ii  php7.0-mysql                                  7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                      amd64        MySQL module for PHP
ii  php7.0-opcache                                7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                      amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
ii  php7.0-readline                               7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                      amd64        readline module for PHP
ii  php7.0-xml                                    7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                      amd64        DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
```

---

### 4) `$ which php`  or `$ which php7.0`

Output:

`/usr/bin/php` or `/usr/bin/php7.0`

## However, I can't uninstall `php` anymore:

```
$ sudo apt remove php
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'php' is not installed, so not removed
```

Comment: The `php` package has been successfully removed, as demonstrated by the fact that it does not appear in the `dpkg -l` output. What is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: @fkraiem I wanted to have a clean installation of `php`, But it wasn't possible since the program was still up and working on my system

Comment: If by "the program" you mean the `php` executable, it is part of the `php7.0-cli` package, so if you want to uninstall it, you need to remove that package.

Comment: @fkraiem Yes, I meant `php`.  I thought all `php` packages including its modules and `php7.0-cli` would be uninstalled by just uninstalling the `php` package itself since it's a meta-package I assume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `apt` description of `php`:

> This package is a dependency package, which depends on Ubuntu's
>   default PHP version (currently 7.2).

So you have deinstalled `php` which was ensuring that you have the latest Ubuntu `php` installed,  but not the individual php packages themselves.

To do this now, you have to purge with 'php*': `sudo apt purge php-*` and `sudo apt purge php7.0*` should do the trick. Purge the `libapache2-mod-php7.0` by hand with `sudo apt purge libapache2-mod-php7.0`. This avoids a conflict with the package management if you just try to remove `php*`.

After that, php is fully removed. For reinstall, just use php since it has all dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. But by entering: `sudo apt purge php*` I got this error message:  `E: Unable to locate package php.tar.gz
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php.tar.gz'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php.tar.gz'`

Comment: I tried a dry run on my own system, which showed the desired results. Which distribution are you running on? I have 18.04, although this shouldn't make a difference.

What happens if you try `sudo apt purge php7.0*`?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 16.04.4.  `sudo apt purge php7.0*` did the job! Why wasn't `sudo apt purge php*` working? Although still some `php` packages remained (`php-common, php-cli-prompt, php-symfony-process, php-symfony-finder, php-composer-semver, php-composer-spdx-licenses, php-symfony-console, php-symfony-filesystem`) Which I got rid by `sudo apt purge php-*`. But I still haven't got what caused the issue. Should I uninstall the `php` by mentioning `php7.0*` and not bare `php`?

Comment: I think there is some weirdness happening if you try to remove something `name*` where a package `name` also exists. I edited my answer accordingly already. 

In your case, you would need to get rid of `php`, `php-*`, `php7.0*` and the `libapache2-mod-php7.0` package to get a clean system.